# Add input textbox into Ruby form dynamically through jQuery and store that values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I have a Ruby form, whatever the value on that storing correctly in the DB. However, if I add a new text box dynamically through jQuery that value is not adding into DB. Below is my code:

```
<%= form_for(@prescription) do |f| %>

<%= f.text_field :BP,:autocomplete => "off" %>

<%= f.text_field :sugar,  :autocomplete => "off" %>

<%= f.text_field :pulse_rate, :autocomplete => "off" %>
<div id='content_div'></div>
<button type="button" id="add-body-part-btn" class="addBodyPart"> Add Price</button>

<% end %>
```

This is my JavaScript code:

```
<script>
$('#add-body-part-btn').click(function(){

    var body_part_row = '';

    body_part_row += '<input class="body-part" type="text"  name="prescription[price][]"';

    $( "#content_div:last").after(body_part_row);

});
</script>
```

When I click on that button I am getting that input tag. However, I am not able to store in the DB.

I specified that param name on controller as well as model.

Comment: First of all having an attrib like `prescription[price][]` for `name` tag is not preferred & yes it has to have a attrib/variable in model which stores this param.

Comment: Thank you for u r reply. The reason why i have given is above ruby form contain f.text_field but in jquery that i a normal input tag. How can i store a normal input tag in ruby form? is there any way? please tell me.

Comment: If i give the same attribute name `prescription[price][]` in ruby form tag it is working and storing on db. like `f.text_field :price,:name => 'prescription[price][]' %>`